# Python returns "SyntaxError: invalid syntax sys module"

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7, pandas, centos7

I got this error message when trying to get path for Pandas package. I'm using Centos 7 for my project. Pandas already installed in the system. I'm using Python 2.7.10.

```
File "analyze_tweets.py", line 8
    import pandas as pd sys.path.insert(0, "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages")
                          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

My code

```
import sys
import pandas as pd sys.path.insert(0, "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages") //error message here
```

Comment: Make your code contain at most one statement per line.

Comment: what do you mean? this one already in one line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd sys.path.insert(0, "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages")
```

This line contains two statements. Split them into two lines:

```
import pandas as pd
sys.path.insert(0, "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages")
```

Or, if they **must** be in one line, separate them with semicolon (**highly not recomended!!!**):

```
import pandas as pd; sys.path.insert(0, "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages")
```

Comment: Also note that depending on _why_ you're doing the sys.path.insert, you might want to do that before the import pandas as pd